# Representation of error values for large and small raw values

Tags: estimation, sampling, error, measurement-error

Assume a population where the numbers are in the range of [0:200]. Assuming the numbers represent the performance of a program, e.g. seconds, the numbers look like

```
v1 = [20.5, 130.32, 0.01, ...]
```

I have a method that estimates those numbers. That is

```
v2 = [20.7, 132.7, 0.02, ...]
```

As you can see there are some differences between the values, so we can compute the error values (v1/v2) for each item which yields

```
error = [1.009756098, 1.018262738, 2, ...]
```

As you can see for `0.01` and `0.02` the error value is 2x (200%), although the differences is in the order of 10^-2. On the other hand, comparing `130.32` and `132.7` the difference in raw numbers in the order of 10^0, but the error value is 1.8%.

I would like to know if there is a way to better represent the error values especially for small numbers when they are in the same set as large numbers.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. You can apply whatever transformation you want to those numbers. What is the purpose of doing it ?

Comment: As I said, in the error vector, there are large values such as 200%, but in fact the difference between 0.02 and 0.01 is 0.01. In the range of [0:200], there is no difference between 0.01 and 0.02. However, the difference between 132 and 130 is 2 while the correspondent error is 1.8%.   Just looking at error values, 200% is a lot, but such a large error occurs for very small numbers.

Comment: both relative and absolute errors can be relevant in different scenarios. It all depends on what *you* want to use them for. I don't think you can expect other people to guess what you are interested in

Comment: If you look at the example about celcuis and kelvin differences, in the end it is written "Thus the relative error is not very meaningful". Does that mean when relative error is not meaningful, we have to use absolute error? Or there is another metric for such situation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error#Examples